# Learn python the hard way, ex52

Tags: python, html, session, storage, counter

The code is

```
import web

web.config.debug = False

urls = (
    "/count", "count"
    "/reset", "reset"
    )

app = web.application(urls, locals())
store = web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app, store, initialzer = {'count': 0})

class count:
    def GET(self):
        session.count += 1
        return str(session.count)

class reset:
    def GET(self):
        session.kill()
        return ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and according to the context, it says "To make this work, you need to create a sessions/ directory where the application can put session storage. Do that, run this application, and go to /count. Hit refresh and watch the counter go up. Close the browser and it forgets who you are, which is what we want for the game. There’s a way to make the browser remember forever, but that makes testing and development harder. If you then go to /reset and back to /count, you can see your counter reset because you’ve killed the session."

I tried to go to the address http://localhost:8080 but it says ""HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico" - 500 Internal Server Error".

Comment: You probably want `app.run()` in the main, not `app.run`.

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: that "app.run" was a typo. the problem rises up as I mentioned with "app.run()"

Answer (score 1):

Try to access http://localhost:8080/count to get the count, and then http://localhost:8080/reset to reset it. This should work.